# Huffman Algorithm is meant for what types of data?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, huffman-code

I have been reading about this algorithm, and i understand building the tree, and what the output should be at the end of the tree process. All the examples are of text files, but for other types of files, you need to read it as a binary file ? In case you do that, how do you select how many bits would make a symbol ? Huffman's algoritm works with any type of file ? And if it doesn´t in what types of files should i focus?

I´m new to the subject so i hope someone can clear things a little bit for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose how many bits should make up each symbol and the number of bits you choose will affect the amount of compression you get by varying amounts depending on the structure of the data that you are compressing. According to H F Smith (1987) *Data Structures : Form and Function*, pp.399-400, for example:

> ... the net savings by this method may not be very great unless we are
>   dealing with a rather small collection of messages in which some are
>   much more likely than others. It is often possible to obtain an
>   improved compression of redundancy [through Huffman encoding] by
>   considering larger segments of the message string than just individual
>   symbols.